# the JSON object must be str, not 'list' - TypeError

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x

I am loading JSON data in My Database but is giving me error - 
`TypeError - the JSON object must be str, not 'list'`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

import json
from .models import Movie

def detail(request):

    with open('movie_data.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
        json_data = json.loads(data_file.read())
        print(type(json_data))

    json_dict = json.loads(json_data)
    for movie_data in json_dict:
        movie = Movie.create(**movie_data)
        # movie and genres created
```

Json file - `movie_data.json`

```
[
  {
    "99popularity": 83.0,
    "director": "Victor Fleming",
    "genre": [
      "Adventure",
      " Family",
      " Fantasy",
      " Musical"
    ],
    "imdb_score": 8.3,
    "name": "The Wizard of Oz"
  },
  {
    "99popularity": 88.0,
    "director": "George Lucas",
    "genre": [
      "Action",
      " Adventure",
      " Fantasy",
      " Sci-Fi"
    ],
    "imdb_score": 8.8,
    "name": "Star Wars"
  },
]
```

I think the json should be converted to dictionary. How can i do that. I don't know what is the problem. I am reading the json file. It should be string file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to call `json.loads()` twice.  Remove the second call.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, no nead for `json.loads()` twice. And when you do use it at `json_data = json.loads(data_file.read())`, it is structured as a list of dictionaries.